# VSCode Launch in subfolder for Jest tests

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs, vscode-debugger

I am working in a monorepo that has `jest.config.js` and `package.json` files in subfolders that represent independent projects in this monorepo, example:

```
items/thing/
items/other/
items/something/
```

In VSCode, if I have a test file in focus, I can then use this config item to run that test file in the `items/thing/` folder.

```
"name": "Jest (this file)",
"type": "node",
"request": "launch",
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/items/thing",
"runtimeArgs": [
    "--inspect-brk",
    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
    "${relativeFile}"
],
```

However, to do the same in the `items/other/` folder I need to change the `cwd` property to that value.

Is there a way to "tie" the `cwd` to the closest parent that has the config/package files so I don't have to adjust the `launch.json` settings each time? (Or another way to solve this?)